# wheel colliders went bonkers (unity URP)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, urp

I got a simple script for driving.
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4HA8zJhGEk)
I used this script before everything ok.
I did everything like the youtuber but my wheel colliders are weird.
When ever I accelerated 10kmh or so my car would start shaking and flip over.
Why and how can it be fixed.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Please edit your question and post your code allowing other users to examine [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to solve your problem.

Comment: okay the script isnt the one who makes the cookoos i THINK its the wheel collider but still i edited my q:

Comment: im having problems putting code there ill send a txt document

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kz4ev658j4dhY0OiXUEWseC4mIvEeFtY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please help the car controller is a vital thing for a car simulator 

Comment: Please put the code inside your question, as links tend to expire and it's just easier that way. Also, this article may be useful [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem a while back!
It's from the physics and not all of the wheels being aligned correctly.

Start from scratch using:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html

Make sure all the coordinates are an exact match.
Then u can work off of that to match your transform.

Hope this helps!